# What does the term Plain Old PHP Object (POPO) exactly mean?

Tags: php

I would like to know about popo. I have searched popo and found it stands for Plain Old Php Object.
But I am not sure the exact meaning of Plain Old Php Object.
I want to know what is popo and where to use it?
Thanks.

Comment: Where have you seen it used?

Comment: [same concept](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object).

Comment: Hello mister, I want to know what is the POPO same with?

Comment: Did you read it? It references POPO. Same "concept."

Comment: Then Kindly check here.   https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/releases  
and search "popo".

Comment: @WhiteSnow I added a more extensive example on my answer.  When I think of a plain object, I think of stdClass.  But looking at the Laravel comment you made, they consider a named class still a plain object if it doesn't extend another class or implement an interface.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Plain Old {Insert Language Here} Object is an simple approach that says you don't always need to use an extensive class, or inheritance chain, to store data or perform logic.   It allows you to simplify the understanding of your structure by encapsulating details, not deriving details or creating dependencies on other sources.

A simple use case could be a DTO or Entity that encapsulates user fields:

```
class User  {
    public $firstName;
    public $lastName;
}
```

Versus a more extensive object that implements an interface or extends a Base class or both.

```
interface UserInterface {

    public function getName();
    public function setName($name);

}

class User extends Model implements UserInterface {

    public function getName()
    {
        ...
    } 

    public function setName($value) {
        ...
    }

}
```

According to Wikipedia, a named class is considered a plain object if it does not implement any interfaces or extend any preexisting classes.

I recommend looking at Shaunak Sontakke's answer for use cases.

Comment: Your `versus` example has a misleading fact. `protected` members of a class cannot be accessed outside. You could make it to `public` to avoid misleading even though it's just an example to make the OP understand the concept.

Comment: @Perumal93 thanks, fixed.  Just typed protected out of habit I suppose.

Comment: `stdClass` is also the _default_ class.  JSON decodes to it and casting to `(object)` casts to it.

Comment: you're missing a > symbol on the return value of getValue()

Comment: The idea of a Plain old object is about removing a lot of the complexity (ie ORM, DTO, DAO). The idea really came from POJO (Java) because they like acronyms and giving that lead to more use of these less complex clean class. Calling it with `stdClass` is not completely needed if you wanted the contract.

Answer (score 13):

POPO is as an object of a simple class. When you make it as a stdClass object it's not a strict contract of what you would have in that object. stdClass object can be easily abused by other developers.

Consider below points while making a POPO:

- All member variables are private. Accessor methods should be used vs direct member access.
- Public accessor methods ( getters / setters )
- Public toArray(), toJson() like methods for easy access, easy storage/persistence
- Constructor accepting array of values that need to be set.
- It should not have any business logic
- Avoid any kind of validation in this object
- Don't worry about implementing an interface for POPO. [Optional]
- If you need method chaining, return $this from your setters. [Optional]
- Probably a __toString() method [Optional]

**When to use it:**

Consider use of POPO in these cases:

- To transfer data across the boundary. Like transferring data from Model to Controllers or from controllers to View or from one application to other application. In this case it would behave like Data Transfer Object (DTO). More details - [DTO vs Value Object vs POCO](https://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2015/04/13/dto-vs-value-object-vs-poco/)
- If we have a json data, we could bind that json data and map it to a POPO. So we exactly know what's there in json field. This will also ensure that our json data has a consistent structure always. It will also prevent abuse of JSON structure.
- If there are too many parameters for a function, we could use "[Introduce Parameter Object](https://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html)" refactoring to replace all those parameters with a POPO containing those members.
- For mapping a [database composite type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/rowtypes.html)

POPO is a PHP variant of [POJO](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/POJO.html) that was coined by Martin Fowler

eg:

```
class CPerson {

private $m_strNameFirst;
private $m_strNameLast;
private $m_fltHeight;
private $m_fltWeight;

public function __construct( $arrmixValues ) {
    $this->setNameFirst( $arrmixValues['name_first'] ?? NULL );
    $this->setNameLast( $arrmixValues['name_last'] ?? NULL );
    $this->setHeight( $arrmixValues['height'] ?? NULL );
    $this->setWeight( $arrmixValues['weight'] ?? NULL );
}

public function toArray() : array {
    return [
        'name_first' => $this->getNameFirst(),
        'name_last'  => $this->getNameLast(),
        'height'     => $this->getHeight(),
        'weight'     => $this->getWeight(),
    ];
}

public function getNameFirst() {
    return $this->m_strNameFirst;
}

public function setNameFirst( $strNameFirst ) {
    $this->m_strNameFirst = $strNameFirst;
}

public function getNameLast() {
    return $this->m_strNameLast;
}

public function setNameLast( $strNameLast ) {
    $this->m_strNameLast = $strNameLast;
}

public function getHeight() {
    return $this->m_fltHeight;
}

public function setHeight( $fltHeight ) {
    $this->m_fltHeight = $fltHeight;
}

public function getWeight() {
    return $this->m_fltWeight;
}

public function setWeight( $fltWeight ) {
    $this->m_fltWeight = $fltWeight;
}

}
```

Comment: POJO and getter/setters are very Java specific. There are lot of libraries that rely on the getter/setter for reflection. So in Java that is an expectation. I would not enforce something like that on PHP

Comment: @nerdlyist So are you suggesting to skip getter / setters and make all member variables as public, so they can be directly set?

Comment: Make the attributes that are logically public public and the ones that are only supposed to be used by the class or system as private. In php that would be a plain old object. Now when you use something like an orm it becomes a very different type of object and you have to follow that api contract.

Comment: Underrated answer, I wish more answers would include examples and use cases.

Answer (score 2):

Its from [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object)

> In software engineering, a plain old Java object (POJO) is an ordinary
>   Java object, not bound by any special restriction and not requiring
>   any class path.

http://www.javaleaks.org/open-source/php/plain-old-php-object.html