# Call to undefined method stdClass::getModified()

Tags: php, laravel, auditing, laravel-auditing

Laravel v5.7.24
Laravel Auditing v8.0.4
PHP version 7.3.1

I've a specific problem related to package [Laravel Auditing](https://github.com/owen-it/laravel-auditing). Although I set the Model and everything like in documentation, the blade template is showing me an error `Call to undefined method stdClass::getModified()`. Thank you so much.

Here's my Model:

```
namespace App;

use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;

class Post extends Model implements Auditable
{
    use Searchable, \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;

    protected $fillable = [...];
    protected $auditExclude = [...];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Blade view:

```
<ul>
     @forelse ($audits as $audit)
                <li>
                    @foreach ($audit->getModified() as $attribute => $modified)
                            <ul>
                                <li>@lang('article.'.$audit->event.'.modified.'.$attribute, $modified)</li>
                            </ul>
                    @endforeach
                </li>
            @empty
        <p>@lang('article.unavailable_audits')</p>
    @endforelse
</ul>
```

Comment: Please can you show the controller method as well?

Comment: You're right, problem was in my controller. For more info see answer below. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the error message (`Call to undefined method stdClass::getModified()`) refers to `stdClass` and not `Audit`, I'll take a wild guess and presume you're doing something like `DB::table('audits')->where('auditable_type', Post::class)->get()` to fetch the audits, which returns the results as [POPO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188002/what-does-the-term-plain-old-php-object-popo-exactly-mean), not `Audit` instances.

Try this instead: `Audit::where('auditable_type', Post::class)->get()`

Comment: Oh well.. thank you so much, it was definitely my fault. This helps me. Thank you!